# Is it true the following theorem: If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = A $ and $\lim_{x\to A} f(x) = B $ then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = B $ ? Justify your answer

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it true the following theorem: If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = A $ and $\lim_{x\to A} f(x) = B $ then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = B $ ? Justify your answer

I think that I should show a function which denies the theorem but I can't find which one...

Comment: If you can't find a function which denies it, have you tried proving it's true?

Comment: yeah i tried. If  $ lim_{x\to a} g(x) = A \Rightarrow g(a) = A \text{ and if } \lim_{x\to A} f(x) = B \Rightarrow f(A) = B $. Considering the following: $$ \lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = B $$ We can say that: $$ f(g(a)) = f(A) = B $$ but this happends when the functions are continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have observed that if $f,g$ are continuous, the statement holds. Hence to find a counterexample, we should find a function that is not continuous at $a$. For example, let

$$f(x)=g(x)=\mathbb1_{\{0\}} = \begin{cases}1 &\text{for } x = 0\\0 &\text{for } x \ne 0\end{cases}$$

Then

$$f(g(x)) = \begin{cases}f(1)=0 &\text{for } x = 0\\f(0)=1 &\text{for } x \ne 0\end{cases}$$

We have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0 = \lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ but $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(g(x))=1\ne 0$.